# Rate Movies in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that will display a user’s movie rating.   The application should allow the user to enter the ratings for five different movies. Each rating should be a number from 1 through 10 only. The application should graph the ratings using a horizontal bar chart made of a row of asterisks (*).Each row should contain from one to 10 asterisks (*). The number of asterisks depends on the movie’s rating. I have to use a tuple to store the name of 5 movies. I'm really new at programming so please be nice lol.

This is what i have so far but I'm struggling:

```
movies = ("Shrek", "Platoon", "Scary Movie II", "Gone With The Wind", "Harvey", "7:4")

rating = int(input ("Enter Movie Rating: "))

for i in range(1,11):

    print ("Rating for movie: ", movies[rating])
    while rating < 0 or rating > 10:
        ratings = int(input("Enter movie rating: ", rating))

    for j in range(rating):
        print ("*"*5,)
```

Comment: You should be asking for "how to print" or "how to store values".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, tuples aren't really for this. You can use a list instead. It's very similar but worth switching to by using [ square brackets ]

```
movies = ["Shrek", "Platoon", "Scary Movie II", "Gone With The Wind", "Harvey", "7:4"]
```

Next, you want to get the for loop to go over every movie, not the range of values that the user is allowed put in. You can loop over the list with

```
for movie in movies:
    print ("Rating for movie: ", movie)
```

So now each part of the list will be temporarily stored as 'movie' one by one as the rest of the code runs.

Next, you need to first set the rating as 0, so that the while loop will run at least once before the user has given a rating.

Don't use input as that can behave in unintended ways.
"raw_input" is what you want to use because that takes in any input as a string.

Also, with int() you'll get an error if someone types something that can't be turned into a whole number. So you should use something called a try, except. These basically allow your code to anticipate an error and continue running if it comes up.

```
rating = 0
while rating < 1 or rating > 10:
    try:
        ratings = int(raw_input("Enter movie rating: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("That's not a valid number.")
```

And lastly, you don't need to loop to do the final print, just multiply the string by the rating.

```
print ("*"*rating)
```

Comment: No problem, glad you could follow it all!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should first iterate on the movie list to get the ratings and then iterate again to print the movie name together with its rating:

```
movies = ("Shrek", "Platoon", "Scary Movie II", "Gone With The Wind", "Harvey", "7:4")
ratings = []

for m in movies:
    ratings.append( input ("Enter Rating for {0}: ".format(m)) )

for m,r in zip(movies,ratings):
    print "{0:<20} : {1}".format(m,'*'*r)
```

Also you don't need to use int() for input since there is an implicit eval

Answer (score 0):

if printing a nice table was the problem then try this:

movies = ["Shrek", "Platoon", "Scary Movie II", "Gone With The Wind", "Harvey"]

rating = [1,2,3,4,5]

num = [0,1,2,3,4]

print "star limit is from 1 to 10"

for x in num:

```
my =int(raw_input("stars for  "+movies[x]+"-----"))


rating[x]= my
```

m = "stars for  "+movies[x]+"-----"

print 30*"_"

for x in num:

```
print "|"+movies[x]+(20-len(movies[x]))*" "+"|"+rating[x]*"*"

print 30*"_"
```

if u like it vote uppp!